# nested default dictionary counting values

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I've got a defaultdict with a nested dictionary from which I'm trying to get the sum of the values. But I've been struggling to find a way to do this.

In the example below, I'm trying to count all the `count` values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = defaultdict(dict)

x['test1']['count'] = 14
x['test4']['count'] = 14
x['test2']['count'] = 14
x['test3']['count'] = 14

print x

""" methods I've tried """

# print x.values()
# print sum(x for y in x.values() for x in y['count'].iteritems())
# print sum(x.itervalues())
```

The methods above that I've tried (in many different variations) didn't provide the desired results.

Any clues or assistance as to where I may be in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to caluculate sum of just `'count'` key, you may do:

```
>>> sum(y['count'] for y in x.values())
56
```

If there is a possibility of having other keys as well (apart from 'count'), and you want to calculate sum of all the values, then you have to do:

```
>>> sum(z for y in x.values() for z in y.values())
56

# OR,
# import itertools
# sum(itertools.chain(*[y.values() for y in x.values()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `sum(x[k]['count'] for k in x)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum the values of all sub dictionaries, sum twice:

```
>>> sum(sum(y.values()) for y in x.values())
56
```